# Is there a way to transfer multiple tables from Hadoop to Oracle?

Tags: oracle, hadoop

I have a few hundred tables I would like to move from Hadoop to Oracle. Currently I am looking into using sqoop jobs however the problem with this approach is that I have to create a table on the Oracle side before I can run the sqoop job. Is there anyway to just do a one time bulk export on the Hadoop side with just the table names? Or do I have to create a empty table with the schema for each of the tables on the Oracle side before I copy it over?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into apache [NIFI](https://nifi.apache.org/).  Many consider it a replacement for Sqoop/Flume.  You may find someone has written a flow that does what you want.    It has the tooling to do the work at least.  I haven't heard of many companies moving from Hadoop to Oracle.  Usually data out grows a database, it does not normally shrink to fit into a database.